# How to remove color formatting of links in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-office

In Microsoft Word for Mac 2011, I'm trying to edit the `Hyperlink` and `FollowedHyperlink` styles so that they don't modify the text's color that I'm hyperlinking.

For example, let's say I have the following words: `red blue green` all written in thier corresponding colors. Next, I decide to highlight these words and hyperlink them. By default, all the text will be turned into blue. That's not what I want; I want all the text to be the same colors, but with an underline added. That is, I would like the word `red` to still appear in red color, not blue.

When I edit the style, it shows this, as you would expect:

> Underline, **Font color: Hyperlink**, Style: Hide until used, Priority: 100, Based on: Default Paragraph Font.

I want to remove the part I bolded, however, I don't see a way to do that. When I click the color icon, there is no option to select "no color." The closest thing to that is "Auto" which just changes the links to be black instead of blue.

Answer (score 1):

How to customize your hyperlink:

<kbd>Home</kbd> → <kbd>Styles Pane</kbd> → <kbd>Followed Hyperlink</kbd> → <kbd>Modify Style</kbd> → <kbd>Formatting</kbd>

Then simply choose the format that you would like :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you go under general setting you can set the default formatting for them...
Its not where you NORMALLY format the text... (i don't have it installed right now..)
go to file and preferences.. ( i think )

Comment: I don't see any options relating to link color in the Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Format > Styles

There you can modify the styles in use for the current document, including hyperlink colours.

Comment: Have you tried this and verified it's working for you as per the OP's request? @Senseful doesn't want a style that changes links to a specific color, they want the hyperlink style to not apply *any* color.

Answer (score 0):

From the "Home" tab, open the "Styles" box.
Select the "Options..." link.
In the "Select styles to show:" dropdown menu, select "All styles" and click OK.
Go back to the Styles menu, select "FollowedHyperlink"
Select "Modify..."
In the Formatting section, choose the color you want and click OK

Comment: There is no way to force the style to have *no* color (i.e. retain text original color).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, you can create a Macro to change the hyperlink color.

```
Sub Linkcolor()
 With ActiveDocument.Styles("Hyperlink").Font
    .Name = ""
    .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    .Color = RGB(80, 200, 210)
  End With
  ActiveDocument.Styles("Hyperlink").BaseStyle = "Default Paragraph Font"
End Sub
```

And then save it as a template with .docm. Then you can save it as a .docx.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

1. 'Home' tab
2. 'Format' section
3. Arrow to drop down
4. Right-click on the 'followed hyperlink' box
5. 'Modify'
6. Choose the 'style property'
7. 'Format'
8. Change the colour
9. Hit 'okay' on each open window

Comment: That's not going to do what the OP asked. They asked how to have the hyperlink style not apply any color at all.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a way to do this. Even hacking the .docx and removing the colors supplied for the hyperlink styles seems to make Word 2016 supply default colors.

The only workaround I can find is to hyperlink the text first, and then supply a different color after.